# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java heap space in websphere

Tags: pdf, memory, memory-leaks, websphere, heap-memory

I am using Websphere and trying to upload a PDF attachment with file size of 51M, it failed with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java heap space.

Can someone help me out to check that issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Websphere has insufficient memory configuration.
Maybe steps below will help:
1) Find pid of Websphere process

2) Run in shell: jinfo your_pid, find memory configuration: -Xms and -Xmx

3) Find Websphere configuration, and augment memory.